# I will do the admob shows up after a seconds...how

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

Here is my code, And i will do like its show up after couple of seconds, Not only in Gameover, There is no gameover function in my app. I will do like the Interstitial Ad showing.

My code is down, If i start the app and click on the soundboard fast there no  Interstitial Ad  showing.

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameScript : MonoBehaviour {
bool hasShownAdOneTime;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    //Request Ad
    RequestInterstitialAds();
}

void Update()
{
    //if (GameScript.isGameOver)
    {
        if (!hasShownAdOneTime)
        {
            hasShownAdOneTime = true;
            Invoke("showInterstitialAd", 2.0f);
        }
    }
}

public void showInterstitialAd()
{
    //Show Ad
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.Show();

        //Stop Sound
        //

        Debug.Log("SHOW AD XXX");
    }

}

InterstitialAd interstitial;
private void RequestInterstitialAds()
{
    string adID = "";

    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = adID;
    #elif UNITY_IOS
    string adUnitId = adID;
    #else
    string adUnitId = adID;
    #endif

    // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

    //***Test***
    // AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    // .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)       // Simulator.
    //.AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b")  // My test device.
    //  .Build();

    //***Production***
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

    //Register Ad Close Event
    //interstitial.OnAdClosed += Interstitial_OnAdClosed;

    // Load the interstitial with the request.
    interstitial.LoadAd(request);

    Debug.Log("AD LOADED XXX");

    }

    //Ad Close Event
    //private void Interstitial_OnAdClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    //{
    //Resume Play Sound

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time to load the ads(10-60 seconds for video ads). So, if you are showing it too early, it won't load. Make sure  `interstitial.IsLoaded()` is returning true.